# Unable to uninstall app consuming lot of memory

Tags: macos, memory, ram

I am using MacBook Air with Catalina OS. When I hit `top` command it shows an app `Electron` consuming about 50% RAM.

I tried uninstalling it but can't find in application list. I have not installed this Electron app explicitly and don't know how it came on my machine.

How to uninstall this as I am not using it?

Top command output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick search shows that Electron is a framework on which google chrome (to name one) runs. So you cant really uninstall it, however you could try, closing a few chrome windows or tabs. A blog gives a solution to this issue by replacing Electron apps as a whole (like using safari instead of chrome), which is not an option for everyone but is worth considering.

[https://medium.com/macoclock/5-apps-that-eat-your-ram-and-how-to-replace-them-91f9f856cd66](https://medium.com/macoclock/5-apps-that-eat-your-ram-and-how-to-replace-them-91f9f856cd66%E2%80%A8)

Personally my advice would be to upgrade to Mac OS Big Sur(if your mac is supported) as I experience some performance increase and found that it was generally more optimised.